# Python scapy "NameError: global name 'LOOPBACK_NAME' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-2.7, scapy

I have this very simple `scapy` program, which does a `arp_ping` to my subnet

```
from scapy.all import srp, Ether, ARP, conf

def arp_ping(subnet):
    conf.verb = 1
    answered, unanswered = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst=subnet),timeout=2,verbose=False, inter=0.1)
    return [rcv.sprintf(r"%Ether.src% - %ARP.psrc%") for snd, rcv in answered]

if __name__=="__main__":
    subnet = '192.168.1.0/24'

    for i in arp_ping(subnet):
        print i
```

---

## EDIT

After reinstalling atleast `PyWin32` and `WinPcap` with [choco](https://chocolatey.org/install) I now have a this **NameError**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "arp_sender.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scapy.all import srp, Ether, ARP, conf
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\all.py", line 16, in <module>
    from scapy.arch import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from scapy.arch.windows import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 465, in <module>
    conf.iface = get_working_if()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 463, in get_working_if
    return LOOPBACK_NAME
NameError: global name 'LOOPBACK_NAME' is not defined
```

## Checking for depencies issue

Running `scapy.bat` to check for depencies results into this message:

```
INFO: Can't load Python libreadline or completer
INFO: Can't import matplotlib. Won't be able to plot.
INFO: Can't import PyX. Won't be able to use psdump() or pdfdump().
WARNING: No match between your pcap and windows network interfaces found. You probably won't be able to send packets. Deactivating unneeded interfaces and restarting Scapy might help.Check your winpcap and powershell installation, and access rights.
INFO: Could not get readline console. Will not interpret ANSI color codes.
WARNING: No default IPv4 routes found. Your Windows release may no be supported and you have to enter your routes manually
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\\scapy", line 25, in <module>
    interact()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\main.py", line 300, in interact
    scapy_builtins = __import__("all",globals(),locals(),".").__dict__
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\all.py", line 16, in <module>
    from scapy.arch import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from scapy.arch.windows import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 465, in <module>
    conf.iface = get_working_if()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 463, in get_working_if
    return LOOPBACK_NAME
NameError: global name 'LOOPBACK_NAME' is not defined
```

---

**My guess is that:**

`WARNING: No match between your pcap and windows network interfaces found. You probably won't be able to send packets. Deactivating unneeded interfaces and restarting Scapy might help.Check your winpcap and powershell installation, and access rights.`

is causing the issue, but I'm unsure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an old scapy version, update it via
`pip install scapy --upgrade` to get 2.4.0

I can see that because recent versions do not need libreadline anymore

In the latest version, the only dependency you need to install is:

- Winpcap or Npcap
- IPython (if asked)

Answer (score 0):

You may have run your Python code as non-administrator.

I just encountered the same problem when I used the PyCharm IDE, which was not opened in the administrator mode (by default).
After I restarted the IDE as the administrator, the error message was gone.

Similarly, when you want to use the scapy library in Linux, you have to specify "sudo ..."